# what llvm store instruction pattern do i need?

Tags: llvm

im trying to make an llvm backend and i dont know what i need to fix this error

```
LLVM ERROR: Cannot select: t5: ch = store<ST4[%retval]> t0, Constant:i32<0>, FrameIndex:i64<0>, undef:i64
```

this is the ir im trying to process

```
define i32 @main() #0 {
%retval = alloca i32, align 4
store i32 0, i32* %retval, align 4
ret i32 0
}
```

but i don't know what dag pattern i need to be able to match it.

a tablegen file that contains some of the instructions my arch supports is here https://github.com/jfmherokiller/customllvm/blob/master/llvm/lib/Target/ZCPU/zcpuInstr.td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just figured out the issue i was looking at the issue wrong

```
store<ST4[%retval]> t0, Constant:i32<0>, FrameIndex:i64<0>, undef:i64
```

can be expessed in function form as                  `store(Constant:i32<0>,FrameIndex:i64<0>)` or store constant i32 0 in 
stack frame index 0.

The information i wasnt getting was that `FrameIndex:i64<0>` directly related to this line in TargetSelectionDAG.td `def frameindex :SDNode<"ISD::FrameIndex",SDTPtrLeaf, [],"FrameIndexSDNode">;`

so FrameIndex = frameindex